# Evento hover en pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Quisiera saber como puedo generar un evento Hover en el boton **bclose** del siguiente codigo para que cuando el mouse este sobre de el cambie su color por ejemplo:

Este es mi codigo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowFlags((Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True )
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0.209, y1:0.006, x2:0.655367, y2:0.404, stop:0 rgba(88, 93, 99, 105), stop:1 rgba(20, 25, 29, 205))")
        self.bclose = QPushButton(self)
        self.bclose.setText("X")
        self.bclose.setStyleSheet("background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));color:'white';font:10pt;border:0px;")
        self.bclose.setGeometry(551,0,50,25)

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.resize(600,400)
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Style Sheet maneja pseudo-estados como hover, checked, pressed, etc. Ademas es recomendable tener una hoja de diseño para no sobreescribir demasiado haciendolo más legible.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

qss = '''
QMainWindow{
    background-color:qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0.209, y1:0.006, x2:0.655367, y2:0.404, stop:0 rgba(88, 93, 99, 105), stop:1 rgba(20, 25, 29, 205))
}
QPushButton{
    background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    color:'white';font:10pt;border:0px;
}
QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: 'red'
}
'''

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowFlags((Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True )
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)
        self.bclose = QPushButton(self)
        self.bclose.setText("X")
        self.bclose.setGeometry(551,0,50,25)
        self.bclose.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    p = Principal()
    p.resize(600,400)
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Información más detallada lo puedes encontrar en los siguientes enlaces:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html